# Get canvas viewport translate when zooming

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, zooming

How i can get translate canvas viewport when zooming?

My zooming method:

```
    mouseZoom(opt) {
        let canvas = this.canvasRender;
        let delta = opt.e.deltaY;
        let zoom = canvas.getZoom();
        zoom = zoom + delta / 200;
        if (zoom > 10 || zoom < 0.2) {
            return;
        }

        if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
        if (zoom < 0.001) zoom = 0.01;
        canvas.zoomToPoint({x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY}, zoom);
        opt.e.preventDefault();
        opt.e.stopPropagation();       
     }
```

Comment: What are you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a popup whose coordinates depend on the coordinates of the object on the canvas, and when I zoom need to recalculate the coordinates for the popup, depending on the zoom factor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `canvas.viewportTransform` property.

It contains all viewport transformation stored as array `[a, b, c, d, tx, ty]`, where:

**a** -– x scale

**b** – y skew

**c** – x scew

**d** – y scale

**tx** – x translation

**ty** – y translation

Comment: I tried this, but tx and ty more than the actual offset. Need some kind of coefficient for them